# Band combinations for identifying limestone quarries

Tags: remote-sensing, classification, landsat, geology

What are the most useful band combinations for identifying current and recently closed limestone quarries (Landsat 5 and Landsat 8)?  In particular, for a dry sparsely vegetated region like much of Oman in the Middle East.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but what do you propose, based on the satellite's wavelengths and the spectrum for your surface type? Concerning "recently closed", do these still contain limestone? You are trying to distinguish between sand an limestone?

Comment: Yes, I was planning to use spectral characteristics.  Essentially, from Google Earth alone it is clear enough where the 'scarring' / cut-outs into the landscape from quarrying are.  So yes essentially, I would be aiming to clarify and quantify the extent of these 'cut-outs' from the surrounding 'untouched' rocks and sand / gravel plains.  There are also quarries for the extraction of hard rock resources (ophiolites), and to smaller scale dimension stone.  I am relatively new to this process of classification as an undergraduate geographer, so apologies if I appear confused.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, when trying to classify new target types, it's probably safest to start with all bands, especially with Landsat since the number of bands is small (there is no memory/processing constraint that requires feature selection, as would be the case in hyperspectral imagery). Most classifiers will be able to show some statistic about which bands were most used, and if those measures are consistent you can then restrict your bands further. You will also usually get some gains by using multiple images over the same site, which will lead to vegetation, soil moisture, etc. differences that could potentially help distinguish the class of interest.

Note that for specific mineral identification, hyperspectral sensors tend to be the better option.

Comment: Thanks, I will take some time to explore and read into your insights.  In respect to an unsupervised classification it would appear that a large number of buildings generate the same spectral signatures as my quarry sites (both for 30 and 10 class classifications).  They are largely separated spatially so common sense allows for identification but I am unsure if there is a way to 'fix' this in a more spectral-related sense.  I am in the process of also thinking about training sites for a supervised classification and I wonder if maybe the problem will re-emerge again.

Comment: You can use segmentation or even a basic sieve filter in post-processing to remove objects smaller than a given size, I think quarries tend to be larger than most structures.